# ASP.NET ejecutar OnClick si tengo un preventDefault

Tags: asp.net

Buenas comunidad, sucede lo siguiente:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGuardar" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnGuardar_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= btnGuardar.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
            if (document.getElementById("<%=txtPatente.ClientID%>").value == "") {
                document.getElementById("<%=alertResult.ClientID%>").className = "alert alert-danger";
                document.getElementById("<%=txtPatente.ClientID%>").focus();
                $('#<%= lblEstado.ClientID %>').html("Ingrese una patente");

            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

El script la uso para una validación por lo que necesito que no haga un `postback`.. pero también necesito que se ejecute el código del lado del servidor  y no lo estaría realizando de esta forma, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes mezclar evento de asp.net con código del lado del cliente y que funcionen integrados, o usas eventos o usas codigo javascript (o jquery)

Por el planteo que realizas recomendaría evalues de hacer uso del `$.ajax` para poder invocar `webmethod` del lado del servidor, en definitiva te olvidas de los eventos de asp.net y trabajas con evento del lado del cliente invocando al servidor usando ajax

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

El boton debería ser un html

```
<input type='button' value='Guardar' id='guardar' />
```

entonces en javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {

        $('#guardar').click(function (e) {

            if ($("#<%=txtPatente.ClientID%>").val() == "") {
                $("#<%=alertResult.ClientID%>").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                $("#<%=txtPatente.ClientID%>").focus();
                $('#<%=lblEstado.ClientID %>').html("Ingrese una patente");
                return;
            }

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "page1.aspx/WebMethodName",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    //codigo
                },
                failure: function(response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

de esta forma tu controlas las validaciones del lado del cliente y cuando invocar la funcionalidad al servidor

En realidad los textbox tambien deberian ser html y el label reemplazarlo por un div

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes:
***"El script la uso para una validación por lo que necesito que no haga un postback"***: Cuando quieras ejecutar en el lado del cliente, te recomiendo utilizar la propiedad `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGuardar" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return MiFuncion();" />
```

Reemplaza:

```
$('#<%= btnGuardar.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
```

Por:

```
function MiFuncion() {   
//y con la siguiente linea jamás hará un postback
return false;
```

Ahora ***"pero también necesito que se ejecute el código del lado del servidor"*** Depende de lo que necesites, podrías utilizar el control de validación [ASP.net WebForms Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/a0z2h4sw(v=vs.100).aspx) y asignar la lógica que lo requiera (Recomendado).

Si se te hace medio complicado la opción anterior, también podrías crear otro botón al lado del botón mencionado lineas arriba, dicho botón se mantiene oculto y que se muestre cuando la validación es correcta (y se oculte nuevamente cuando no lo es), es decir el `btnGuardar` que tienes sería un `btnValidar` y si la validacion es correcta, entonces mostrar `btnGuardar` y a ese mismo lo vinculas con el `code-behind`, estarías haciendo que el usuario verifique y luego confirme.